# 2D overlap line chart

Tags: java, drawing, charts

Does any one know of an API that would allow me to draw something like this. It would need some interactivity to it

- zooming
- change second dimension axis angle

I was looking at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) but I don't see any example of doing 2D overlap chart.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did this quite recently.  Pretty simple, really.  I can send you the code to draw the base grid, and the rest is just a series of histograms (Polygons) with an offset between each layer.

Comment: Hi, that sounds great. Please email it to me on danielgq.chong@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

May be [Chart3D](http://www.tan.co.jp/JClass/Chart3D) might be what you are after (not free though)

[image: http://www.tan.co.jp/images/jclass/chart3d/3d_4e.gif?width=260&height=173&quality=95&sharpen=0.15&format=jpeg]

A more simple and free solution might be a [SpiceChart 3D line](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/19/38/).

Comment: it may do what i'm after, but I can't afford to pay US$4500 for it. Not the in academic setting I work in.

Comment: I understand totally :) Still looking for alternatives